# Bash progress dialog with rich progress report

Tags: bash, dialog

I have `dialog` installed, where I would like to have a nice progress dialog, like this:

```
+-------[ title ]--------+
|                        |
| +-[ console output ]-+ |
| | output line1       | |
| | output line2       | |
| +--------------------+ |
| #########80%#####::::: |
+------------------------+
```

So, for example when upgrading 5 packages in a distro, it shows the progress (here, 3 package is upgraded out of 5), but shows the detailed output of the executed commands. Is this possible?

Comment: check for the dialog's `-gauge` box.

Comment: I know, I know, but then how would I display the output of the runned command?

Comment: maybe it belongs to linux-unix. Could someone migrate the question to there, or should I dupe this question there?

Comment: Why close? This seemed to be a valid question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250564/bash-multi-gauge/16674353